# Java - Testar se o VLC está instalado

Tags: java

Olá! Estou desenvolvendo um projeto de mod para Minecraft e necessito checar se o VLC está instalado e a VLCj pode rodar normalmente, caso não esteja preciso fechar o jogo é mostrar uma mensagem. Alguém sabe como eu poderia fazer a parte da verificação?

Comment: Poste algum código para que seja mais fácil para outros membros te ajudar.

Comment: A sua dúvida é sobre como verificar se um arquivo existe usando código Java, ou sobre qual é o arquivo da VLC do Minecraft para o mod de seu interesse? Se for a primeira, edite a pergunta pra deixar isso claro (e indique o nome do arquivo que você quer verificar se existe). Se for a segunda, ela está fora do escopo do site (nesse caso, leia a [help] e faça o [tour]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se entendi bem, é possível usar uma rotina da própria biblioteca VLCj para isso.

O método [`discover`](http://caprica.github.io/vlcj/javadoc/3.9.0/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/discovery/NativeDiscovery.html#discover--) da classe `NativeDiscovery` faz uma busca pelas bibliotecas nativas `libvlc` e retorna `true` caso forem encontradas ou `false` se não forem.

Para usar a classe acima provavelmente vai precisar também instanciar uma [`StandardNativeDiscoveryStrategy`](http://caprica.github.io/vlcj/javadoc/3.9.0/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/discovery/StandardNativeDiscoveryStrategy.html).